# Add custom response header traefik ingress on K3S

Tags: traefik, k3s, traefik-ingress

How does one add a custom response header to  `traefik` ingress on a K3S ?
I have followed the official doc and a few answers from stackoverflow. But none seems to work.

Here is my ingress:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: traeffic-custom-response-header
  namespace: mynamespace
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/custom-response-headers: Bypass-Tunnel-Reminder:true
    ingress.kubernetes.io/custom-response-headers: Bypass-Tunnel-Reminder:true
spec:
  rules:
  - host: localhost
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: scc-worker
            port:
              number: 8000
```

I am running a local K3S cluster on my PC for testing.
And I am not able to add custom response header.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I solved this issue by adding middleware and then configuring it in my Ingress Controller Configuration

```yaml
---
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: add-bypass-tunnel-header
  namespace: mynamespace
spec:
  headers:
    customResponseHeaders:
      Bypass-Tunnel-Reminder: "true"

---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: traeffic-custom-request-header
  namespace: mynamespace
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.entrypoints: web
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.middlewares: mynamespace-add-bypass-tunnel-header@kubernetescrd
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/custom-response-headers: Bypass-Tunnel-Reminder:true
    ingress.kubernetes.io/custom-response-headers: Bypass-Tunnel-Reminder:true
spec:
  rules:
  - host: localhost
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: scc-worker
            port:
              number: 8000
```

Here `add-bypass-tunnel-header` is a middle ware being created
And then adding it to traefik ingress by `traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.middlewares: mynamespace-add-bypass-tunnel-header@kubernetescrd` annotation